# SQL Grouping cube and pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, grouping, cube

I'm trying to do the following query where I obtain a table grouping by years, month and sites, and then I pivot this sites to columns:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
  DECODE(GROUPING(TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'YYYY'))
    ,0, TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'YYYY') 
    ,1, 'TOTAL') AS "YEAR",

  DECODE(GROUPING(TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'MM'))
    ,0, TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'MM') 
    ,1, 'TOTAL') AS "MONTH",  

  DECODE(GROUPING(TS.CODIGO5)
    ,0, TS.CODIGO5
    ,1, 'TOTAL') AS BU,

  SUM(TM.KWHGEN) AS GEN

FROM T_MEDIDAS_CO TM
    JOIN T_Sede TS ON TM.id_sede=TS.id_sede
  WHERE TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'YYYY') IN (2015,2014)
  AND TS.CODIGO5 IN ('FINSI', 'FINOC')
    GROUP BY CUBE (TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'YYYY'), TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'MM'), TS.CODIGO5)
 ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'YYYY') DESC, TO_CHAR(TM.TIMESTAMP,'MM') DESC, 3

)
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(GEN)
   FOR BU IN ('FINCI' AS FINCI,'FINSI' AS FINSI, 'FINOC' AS FINOC, 'TOTAL' AS TOTAL)
)

ORDER BY "YEAR" DESC, "MONTH" DESC
```

to obtain this result

```
YEAR    MONTH    FINCI        FINOC        TOTAL
2015    12      110376,17   109991,55   220367,72
2015    11      92032,56    97938,09    189970,65
2015    10      77668,67    79273,98    156942,65
2015    09      87079,46    91203,73    178283,19
2015    08      99992,38    100220,24   200212,62
2015    07      142430      133979,74   276409,74
2015    06      107006,73   104320,96   211327,69
2015    05      86264       90985,62    177249,62
2015    04      85838,41    87147,74    172986,15
2015    03      106178,39   106342,4    212520,79
2015    02      125007,65   122790,76   247798,41
2015    01      134934,67   135897,7    270832,37
2015    TOTAL   1254809,09  1260092,51  2514901,6
2014    12      121185,25   122014,9    243200,15
2014    11      94682,9     94221,47    188904,37
2014    10      87212,59    92222,92    179435,51
2014    09      97306,19    100701,93   198008,12
2014    08      97738,26    101901,88   199640,14
2014    07      113242,07   117496,84   230738,91
2014    06      98234,69    98092,2     196326,89
2014    05      91202,74    102214,94   193417,68
2014    04      88517,65    103756,83   192274,48
2014    03      107541,53   119236,48   226778,01
2014    02      127880,75   131451,38   259332,13
2014    01      141381,35   143836,44   285217,79
2014    TOTAL   1266125,97  1327148,21  2593274,18
TOTAL   12      231561,42   232006,45   463567,87
TOTAL   11      186715,46   192159,56   378875,02
TOTAL   10      164881,26   171496,9    336378,16
TOTAL   09      184385,65   191905,66   376291,31
TOTAL   08      197730,64   202122,12   399852,76
TOTAL   07      255672,07   251476,58   507148,65
TOTAL   06      205241,42   202413,16   407654,58
TOTAL   05      177466,74   193200,56   370667,3
TOTAL   04      174356,06   190904,57   365260,63
TOTAL   03      213719,92   225578,88   439298,8
TOTAL   02      252888,4    254242,14   507130,54
TOTAL   01      276316,02   279734,14   556050,16
TOTAL   TOTAL   2520935,06  2587240,72  5108175,78
```

But, I don't need the TOTAL | MONTH rows, how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove  'TOTAL' AS TOTAL in your PIVOT clause

Comment: Thanks Mihai. But the problem is that I need that last column where I sum up horizontally

Comment: Well, I got it. Sometimes the solution is more simple than you think. Adding "WHERE NOT ("YEAR" = 'TOTAL' AND "MONTH" IN ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')) above the last line.